# Visual Basic 6, multiple criteria in SQL = SELECT FROM WHERE

Tags: sql, vb6

My knowledge in Visual Basic 6 is basic. What is wrong with this code? And what would be a little tutorial if possible?

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE " & "JOB" & " like '" & searchkey & "%'" And "CloseJob" & " like '" & "NO" & "%'"
```

I tried searching for it, but I can't find any Visual Basic 6 code for multiple criteria. Or I'm just terrible in searching, hehe.

The original code was

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE " & "JOB" & " like '" & searchkey & "%'"
```

so I thought by adding `AND` at the end, and make another criteria would solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AND` needs to be inside the quotes:

```
    SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE " & _
          "JOB like '" & searchkey & "%' And CloseJob like 'NO%'"
```

Basically, all this line is doing is concatenating strings, and in this case, the only variable that needs to be inserted into the concatenated string is `searchkey`.

On a side note, I added the vb6 line continuation: `& _` for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something as below, where you would replace  with the column name and the variable name, respectively.  This gets anything like somethingElse with a wildcard on both ends.

```
SQL = "SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE JOB LIKE '" & searchkey & "%' AND CloseJob LIKE 'NO%'"
```